# How to search and match string with brackets using re?

Tags: python, regex

I am trying to match a pattern with `my_stats1` from the file which consists of the same pattern from the list. But while trying to search the pattern it is failing.
*Contents of my file:*

```
AAAA AA AAAAAAA           (Count) : 10
BB BB BBB           (Count) : 10
```

My code:

```
my_stats1 = 'AAAA AA AAAAAAA           (Count)'
a = []
b = []
with open('stats') as fp:
    for line in fp:
        a.append(line)
    fp.close()
my_stats1_val= ([x for x in a if re.search(x, my_stats1)])
print my_stats1_val
```

The output is null: `[]`.

Comment: I suspect the line you read from the file has a trailing newline. You can check that with `print(repr(line))`. Use `a.append(line.strip())` to remove all whitespaces from the beginning and end of the value you add to the list.

Comment: BTW, you don't need `fp.close()`. The `with` statement handles that for you.

Comment: It is not the trailing lines , but the addition of brackets(). I have checked without brackets it worked fine. Just needed complete string match even with spaces till the ':'

Comment: And a last point. According to your `print` statement you're still using Python 2, 10 years after the announcement that Python 2 will no longer be supported in 2020. You really, really should switch to Python 3 now.

Comment: Finally I understand what was asked in the question. You'll have to use [`re.escape`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/re.html#re.escape) (`a.append(re.escape(line.strip()))`), otherwise the parentheses will be seen as a group definition.

Comment: The output of the list is ['AAAA\\ AA\\ AAAAAAA\\ \\ \\ \\ \\ \\ \\ \\ \\ \\ \\ \\(Count\\)\\ \\ \\:\\ 10\\ \\ \\ \\ \\ \\ \\ \\ \\ \\ \\ \\\n',  'BBBB\\ BB\\ BBBBBBB\\\t\\\t\\:\\ 20\\ \\ \\ \\ \\ \\ \\ \\ \\ \\\n'] yet the pattern/string in my_stats1 did not match from the list

Comment: So much for "It is not the trailing lines". In my first comment I suspected trailing newlines. Now I see them. The `\n` at the end of each string.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
import re

my_stats1 = 'AAAA AA AAAAAAA           (Count)'
with open('test.txt') as fp:
    a = fp.readlines()
rex = re.escape(my_stats1)
my_stats1_val= [x for x in a if re.search(rex, x)]
print my_stats1_val
```

Prints:

```
['AAAA AA AAAAAAA           (Count) : 10\n']
```

Comment: I wasn't interested in writing a full answer anymore. Thanks for putting it all together.

Comment: @Matthias From the OP's last comment it seems that he was mystified as to why there was still no match and I did not see anyone pointing out that even after removing the trailing newline and escaping there just is no match. It's also possible that he is searching "backwards". Perhaps the OP means to be using `my_stats1` as the regex and searching each line in `stats`. In that case there would be one match.

Comment: I guess the question I asked itself was not clear. I want the parentheses to be considered while matching my string as I have more than 10 strings with the same pattern except for the ones in parantheses. I do not have a problem with the trailing lines. Thank you for your suggestion.

Comment: The parentheses are considered but as "regular" characters and not as designating a *capture group*.

Comment: @Booboo, Yes I am using the my_stats1 as the regex and searching each line in stats. I can search directly from the file using a for loop, but I want to check if I can do the same from the list using re.

Comment: Then your code is backwards. The way you posted it, you are using each line in `stats` as regex to see if it matches `my_stats1`. I will update my answer to show how it should go.

Comment: @Booboo Thank you so much. It worked. I am bit new to regex so found it hard in explaining the actual problem. Thank you once again.

Comment: I should add that in this particular case you really did not need to use the power of regular expressions. You could have just said: `my_stats1_val= [x for x in a if my_stats1 in x]`, which does a simple search for string `my_stats1` in string `x` and returns `True` or `False` according to whether it is found or not.